# Is there any default way in elasticsearch to save the searches

Tags: elasticsearch

I have implemented Elasticsearch in our website,if we search any keyword in our website i want to save the search history so that in future i can keep a track of the keyword that we search.
If there is any default way to save the searches in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 3):

There is a logging functionality for slow searches where all queries with a runtime above a threshold will be logged. If you reduce the treshlod to 0 all searches will be logged.

Please have a look here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html

Have Fun!